# Puzzled about the `telnet localhost` and `telnet 0.0.0.0`

Tags: networking, ip

I wrote a simple GO program which listens to `0.0.0.0:9999` and `127.0.0.1:9999`:

```
func main() {
    go bind("0.0.0.0:9999", "111 ")
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        bind("127.0.0.1:9999", "222 ")
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Hour)
}

func bind(address string, content string) {
    fmt.Println("-------------", address, "-----------------")
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(listener.Addr().String())

    conn, _ := listener.Accept()
    for {
        _, err := conn.Write([]byte(content))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

The meaning of the code:

It binds two addresses, and gives different responses to the clients of them

1. binding "0.0.0.0:9999": will send "111 " repeat to client
2. binding "127.0.0.1:9999": will send "222 " repeat to client

And then I use telnet to try different addresses, and the responses are:

- `telnet 127.0.0.1 9999`: `222` (OK)
- `telnet localhost 9999`: `111` (WHY?!)
- `telnet 0.0.0.0 9999`: `222` (WHY?!)
- `telnet <my-internal-ip> 9999`: `111` (OK)

I'm quite confused about some of them:

- `telnet localhost 9999`: `111` (WHY?!)

  `localhost` should point to `127.0.0.1`, so I think it's same to `telnet 127.0.0.1 9999` and the response should be `222`, but the actual one is `111`
- `telnet 0.0.0.0 9999`: `222` (WHY?!)

  I think `0.0.0.0` is not same to `127.0.0.1`, I expect to get response of `111`, but get `222`

I also have a demo project: https://github.com/golang-demos/go-bind-0.0.0.0-127.0.0.1-demo

---

Update: My os is OSX

Comment: using `0.0.0.0` _should_ listen to all addresses on the network

Comment: What does the output mean; what are you expecting; and how does this output differ from that?

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I updated the question and add more explanations

Comment: But not what I asked for. Are we to understand that the server is supposed to respond with the client's remote address?

Comment: @EJP updated again, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Both `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` are resolved to `127.0.0.1` by the OS

`$ ping 0.0.0.0`

```
PING 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
```

`$ping localhost`

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms`
```

`localhost` could resolve to something else depending on `/etc/hosts` file.

An excellent explanation for Linux `ping 0.0.0.0` behavior is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99346/200657).

Comment: For mac, it's different: `PING 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host`